# How do I fix this realloc() invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I allocated a variable struct and I want to reallocate it when I want to add more variables, but I don't understand why this error happens since the variable is already allocated with malloc() initially

defining the struct

```
struct variavel {
    char conteudo[Tamanho_maximo_de_conteudo_da_variavel+ 1];
    char id[Tamanho_maximo_do_id_da_variavel+ 1];
};
```

initializing

```
struct variavel * variaveis = (struct variavel *) malloc(sizeof(struct variavel));
if (variaveis == NULL) {printf("Error"); return 1;}
int qvar = 0;
```

relocating

```
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"var") ) {
                qvar++;
                variaveis = (struct variavel *) realloc(variaveis, qvar * sizeof(struct variavel));
```

It is in this last line that the error occurs.

There are also other structures that work in the same way, I initialize with a cell and are relocated as necessary, but it is only in the variables that the error occurs

complete code of the part that is executed so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "definicoes.h"

struct variavel {
    char conteudo[Tamanho_maximo_de_conteudo_da_variavel+ 1];
    char id[Tamanho_maximo_do_id_da_variavel+ 1];
};
struct label {
  char id[Maximo_de_caracteres_por_linha_de_codigo];
  size_t linha;
};
struct pointer {
    char id[Tamanho_maximo_do_id_da_variavel+ 1];
    char * origem[Tamanho_maximo_de_conteudo_da_variavel+ 1];
};

int main() {
    
    struct label * labels = (struct label *) malloc(sizeof(struct label));
    char code[Maximo_de_linhas_de_codigo][Maximo_de_caracteres_por_linha_de_codigo+ 1], palavras[Maximo_de_caracteres_por_linha_de_codigo+ 1];
    FILE * porco = fopen(Arquivo_de_codigo,"r");
    int k, qlab = 0, nl, qptr = 0;
    struct variavel * variaveis = (struct variavel *) malloc(sizeof(struct variavel));
    struct pointer * ponteiros = (struct pointer *) malloc(sizeof(struct pointer));
    char *buscap;
    int qvar = 0, i, casewas = 0, caselse = 0, numero = 0, i_condition, e_condition = 0, *numero_repeat[3] = {malloc(0), malloc(0), malloc(0)}, i_repeat = 0;
    
    
    
    if (porco == NULL) {
        printf("Erro: Falha ao abrir o arquivo de código.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(nl = 0; fgets(code[nl], Maximo_de_caracteres_por_linha_de_codigo+ 1, porco); nl++) {
        if (nl > Maximo_de_linhas_de_codigo) {
            printf("Erro: O código há mais linhas do que o definido em definicoes.h ou não foi encontrado \"end program\"\n");
            return 1;
        }
        


    }
    for (k = 0; k < nl; k++) {
        while (code[k][0] == ' ') memmove(code[k], code[k] + 1, strlen(code[k]));
        
        while(strstr(code[k], "\r\n\0")) {
            buscap = strstr(code[k], "\r\n\0");
            buscap[0] = '\n', buscap[1] = '\0';
        }
        
        sscanf(code[k], "%[^ ] ", palavras);
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"create")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][7], "%s ", palavras);
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"var") ) {
                qvar++;
                variaveis = (struct variavel *) realloc(variaveis, qvar * sizeof(struct variavel));
                if (variaveis == NULL) {printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar memória para %s\n", &code[k][4]); numero = 1;;}
                sscanf(&code[k][11], "%s ", variaveis[qvar - 1].id);
                strtok(variaveis[qvar - 1].id, "\n");
            } else
            if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"variable")) {
                qvar++;
                variaveis = realloc(variaveis, (qvar) * sizeof(struct variavel));
                if (variaveis == NULL){ printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar memória para %s\n", &code[k][7]); numero = 1;;}
                sscanf(&code[k][16], "%s ", variaveis[qvar - 1].id);
                strtok(variaveis[qvar - 1].id, "\n");
            } else
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"pointer")) {
                qptr++;
                ponteiros = realloc(ponteiros, qptr * sizeof(struct pointer));
                if (ponteiros == NULL) {printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar memória para %s\n", &code[k][6]); numero = 1;;}
                sscanf(&code[k][11], "%s ", variaveis[qvar - 1].id);
                strtok(variaveis[qvar - 1].id, "\n");
            } else
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"section")) { 
                qlab++;
                labels = realloc(labels, qlab * sizeof(struct label));
                if (labels == NULL) {printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar memória para %s\n", &code[k][6]); numero = 1;;}
                sscanf(&code[k][15], "%s ", labels[qlab - 1].id);
                strtok(labels[qlab - 1].id, "\n");
                labels[qlab - 1].linha = k;
            } else {
                printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                numero = 1;
            }
        } else
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"modify")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][7], "%s ", palavras);
            for(i = 0; strcasecmp(palavras, variaveis[i].id); i++)
                    if (i > qvar) {
                        printf("Erro: Variavel não indentificada na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                        numero = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            sscanf(&code[k][8 + strlen(variaveis[i].id)], "%s ", palavras);
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"keyboard")) {
            } else
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"value")) {
            } else
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"name")) {
            } else {
                printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                numero = 1;
            }
            
        } else
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"write")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][6], "%s ", palavras);
            if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"content")) {
                strcpy(palavras, &code[k][14]);
                strtok(palavras, "\n");
                 for(i = 0; strcasecmp(palavras, variaveis[i].id); i++) {
                    if (i > qvar) {
                        printf("Erro: Variavel não indentificada na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                        numero = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
            } else if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"text")) {
            } else {
                printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                numero = 1;
            }
        } else
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"condition")) {
            casewas = 0, caselse = 0, e_condition = k;
            strcpy(palavras, &code[k][10]);
            strtok(palavras, "\n");
            for(i_condition = 0; strcasecmp(palavras, variaveis[i_condition].id); i_condition++) {
                if (i_condition > qvar) {
                    printf("Erro: Variavel não indentificada na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                    numero = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"case")) {
            casewas++;
            if(casewas > caselse && caselse != 0) {printf("Erro: O comando \"else\" deve vir após todos os cases\n"); numero = 1;}
            if(!e_condition) {printf("Erro: O comando \"case\" da linha %d está fora de um bloco condition\n", k + 1); numero = 1;}
        } else
        if(!strcasecmp(code[k],"end condition\n")) {
            casewas = 0, caselse = 0, e_condition = 0;
        } else
        if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"else\n")) {
            caselse++;
            if(caselse == 2){printf("Erro: Não pode haver mais de um comando \"else\" em um condition\n"); numero = 1;}
            if(!e_condition) {printf("Erro: O comando \"else\" da linha %d está fora de um bloco condition\n", k + 1); numero = 1;}
        } else
        if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"goto")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][5], "%s", palavras);
            if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"line")) {
                sscanf(&code[k][10], "%s", palavras);
                for (i = 0; i < strlen(palavras); i++) 
                    if(!isdigit(palavras[i])) {
                        printf("O repeat \"%s\" da linha %d deve ser um numero natural\n", palavras, k + 1);
                        numero = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            } else 
            if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"section")) {
                sscanf(&code[k][13], "%s", palavras);
                palavras[strlen(palavras) + 1] = '\0', palavras[strlen(palavras)] = '\n';
                for (i = 0; i < Maximo_de_linhas_de_codigo; i++) {
                    if(strstr(code[i], "create section")) {
                        buscap = strstr(code[i], "create section");
                        if(!strcmp(palavras, buscap + 15)) break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == Maximo_de_linhas_de_codigo) {
                    printf("Erro: Seção não indentificada na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                    numero = 1;
                    }
            } else {
                printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                numero = 1;
            }
            
        } else
        if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"repeat")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][7], "%s", palavras);
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(palavras); i++) {
                if(!isdigit(palavras[i])) {
                    printf("O repeat \"%s\" da linha %d deve ser um numero natural\n", palavras, k + 1);
                    numero = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            i_repeat = k;
        } else
        if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"comment") || code[k][0] == '\n') {
        } else if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"end")) {
            sscanf(&code[k][3], "%s", palavras);
            if(!(!strcasecmp(palavras,"program") || !strcasecmp(palavras,"condition") || !strcasecmp(palavras,"repeat"))) {
                printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
                numero = 1;
            }
            if(!strcasecmp(palavras,"repeat")) {
                i_repeat = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Erro: Comando não indentificado na linha %d: %s\n", k + 1, palavras);
            numero = 1;
        }
    }
```

I debugged the code to see where the error was and everything seemed to flow normally, when it arrived at realloc the variables point to an empty space since no variables were inserted.

I also copied the parts of the code that only affect the variables and made a new code just with them, and it worked normally. Maybe another part of the code is interfering

Comment: You have failed to demonstrate the problem. Your code doesn't even compile. Please provide runnable code and the necessary inputs to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I notice that the `if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"pointer")) {` block is accessing `variaveis[qvar - 1]`. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: **It is in this last line that the error occurs.** Which error?

Comment: This is phishy: `if (!strcasecmp(palavras,"pointer"))` If you enter that branch, you read into `variaveis[qvar - 1].id);`. When you come here before you increment `qvar` at least to `1`, you will have an illegal memory access. That should probably be `ponteiros[qptr-1]` instead

Comment: This is also phishy: `for(i = 0; strcasecmp(palavras, variaveis[i].id); i++) if (i > qvar)` That loop will only exit when `i == qvar+1` which is which is 2 elements beyond the allowed limit for `variavels`

Comment: `sscanf(&code[k][11], "%s ", variaveis[qvar - 1].id);` None of your `sscanf` calls contains a length limit for the string. You cold easily overrun the `id` array.

Comment: Recommendation: if you want people from around the world to understand your program, identifiers and comments in English work *much* better.

Comment: Where is the code for `definicoes.h`? post something we can compile... Also avoid giant 40-bytes like names like `Tamanho_maximo_de_conteudo_da_variavel`. It helps no one...

Comment: Also consider the portuguese-speaking stack overflow at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I've just started using stack overflow and I don't really know how to use it correctly. But I wanted to thank @gerhardh for solving the problem, thank you Gerhardh!